# Regex that matches at most N digits with unlimited hyphen and space?

Tags: regex

I need a regex that matches at most 9 digits with any number of space and/or hyphen (leading, trailing or within the digits), what should it look like?

I tried:

```
^[0-9 \\-].*?$
```

and

```
^\\d{9}
```

but they only serve part of my purpose and need a way to merge them together.

Thanks!

Comment: any set of inputs and expected outputs you wanna provide?

Comment: Use `^([ -]*\d){1,9}[ -]*$`

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
^(?:[ -]*\d[ -]*){1,9}$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hoF9KD/3)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?:[ -]*\d[ -]*){1,9}`

  - `[ -]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of either a space or a `-`
  - `\d` - matches a digit
  - `[ -]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of either a space or a `-`
  - `{1,9}` - matches 1 to 9 occurrences of a digit preceded or succeeded by either 0+ spaces or 0+ `-`
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Comment: Of course: you still need to trim your matches, as they still include leading/trailing/inbetween non-digits.